# Is there a simple and clean way to access the properties of a join's join?

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I have a piece type `profile` that joins to other, smaller, pieces (`projects` and `resources`). These smaller pieces themselves have joins to pieces as taxonomy terms. I need to list out the term pieces on the `profile`. Is there a dead simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in the ApostropheCMS Docs.

> By default, if the related type has joins of its own, they are not carried out. To carry out "nested" joins, set the withJoins option to an array containing those join field names. You may also use "dot notation" in these names to indicate that you want to follow a series of joins between related types.

https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/schema-guide.html#code-join-by-one-code